# how to style views with appcompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

How to style textviews, edittexts throughout app when theme is extending from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar?

This is not working,

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/myTextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="textViewStyle">@style/myTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="myTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That's exactly how I'm doing it, are you sure the theme is applied to your activity?

Comment: Yes theme is applied and textViewStyle is declared in attrs.xml as well.

Comment: If I specify 'textViewStyle' in attrs.xml, it compiles but does not show style effect. Without specifying it in attrs.xml, it doesn't even compile. It says "No resource found that matches given name: attr 'textViewStyle' on line <item name="textViewStyle">@style/myTextViewStyle</item>

Comment: I don't believe you need to have a non android namespaced element for textViewStyle. So don't create the attribute yourself and only include the android namespaced attribute in the theme.

Comment: considering I am doing this exactly my guess is you haven't add support library 'compile `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'`

Comment: and another guess is that you are setting style while you should set theme like this: `android:theme="@style/myTextViewStyle"`

Comment: @pouya That's exactly how you should not do it because it's style, not a theme. Read more: https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/ and https://medium.com/@malmstein/working-effectively-with-legacy-android-styles-and-themes-92d182323c15

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Maintain *theme* naming convention Theme.ThemeName. It helps with organization. -->
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.TextView</item>
    <!-- AppCompat does not provide its own variant of textViewStyle attribute. -->
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.EditText</item>
</style>

<!-- Maintain *style* naming convention Widget.ThemeName.WidgetName. -->
<!-- TextView is a simple widget, use the parent provided by platform. -->
<style name="Widget.MyApp.TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>

<!-- EditText parent is provided by AppCompat. -->
<style name="Widget.MyApp.EditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

As long as your app or activity has `android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp` defined in manifest it will work.

Couple of notes:

- If you want to provide a default style for another widget try it like so:

  - Override `widgetNameStyle` in your theme.
  - If the attribute doesn't exist, prefix it with `android:`.
  - If that doesn't work then it's a custom widget and that's beyond the scope of this post.
  - Don't override both `android:`-prefixed and unprefixed variants if they exist! Only one works.
  - Unprefixed attribute is from AppCompat, use AppCompat style as parent.
  - Prefixed attribute is from Android SDK, use platform style as parent (`TextView` and `ProgressBar`).
- Don't mix themes and styles. Themes are context-wide applied to whole hierarchies of views (`android:theme` atribute). Styles are for widgets (`style` attribute).